# jQuery: Hide tr of child td that contains ul + print?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing, html-table

I have a `<table>` where certain `<td>` contain `<ul>` and I want it when a specific button is clicked, two things occur:

1. Parent `<tr>` of children `<td>` that contain a `<ul>` are hidden
2. The window is printed after step 1 is executed, so that `<tr>` containing `<ul>` are hidden on the printed sheet

http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/S9YWL/

HTML:

```
<table id="todo-list">
    <tr>
        <td>Entry No UL 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Entry No UL 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <ul>I SHOULD BE HIDDEN WHEN PRINTED</ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Entry No UL 4</td>
    </tr>
</table><p>
```

Click to print

jQuery:

```
function () {
    $('#followup_a').click(followup);
});

function followup() {
    $('#todo-list tr:has(td:has(ul))').hide();
    window.print();
}
```

Comment: Syntax errors. Open the browser's developer console.

Comment: Believe I fixed the syntax issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem I see is the line `function () {`. That is improper syntax. I think what you mean to do is the document ready method of which I'll show in my answer.

Remove the `onClick="window.print()"` from your link and then change your JS to the following:

```
$(function(){ // document . ready call
    $('#followup_a').on("click", function(e) {
        //  if href does not contain `javascript:void(0)` then use
        //  e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default link action
        $("#todo-list tr").filter(function(i) { return $(this).find("> td ul").length > 0 }).hide();
        window.print();
    });
})
```

What this does:

- [**.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) is a nice jquery method that allows you to call on a group of jQuery elements like `$("#todo-list tr")`, which would normally return all table rows, and filter the result object down based on what information returns true.

  - although `$('#todo-list tr:has(td:has(ul))')` should do roughly the same thing
- `href="javascript:void(0)"` is one way to prevent default link action, or, within the click event you could call on [**event.preventDefault()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

### Could also be written as:

```
function followup(e) {
    $("#todo-list tr").filter(function(i) { return $(this).find("> td ul").length > 0 }).hide();
    window.print();
}

$(function(){ // document . ready call
    $('#followup_a').on("click", followup);
})
```

#### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve the same results just defining specific CSS for Print media:

```
@media print
  {
  td.noprint {display:none;}
  }
```

(Just a small example, adapt to your specific needs.)

Comment: This has no way of specifying ONLY TD's that contain UL's, not all TD's.

Comment: You are correct, since CSS has no parent-selector. Nonetheless you may still programatically add the **noprint** class to UL-containing TDs.